# Codeigniter: relational database as Associative array like yii2

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii2, consider two tables parent and child. If child has a relation to the parent then while writing join query it will produce result like

```
Parent[id => 1, 
     firstname => "John",
     lastName => "Miller"
     child => [id : 1, 
               address : some address,
               contact number : some nubmer
     ]
]
```

But in Codeignitor it is displayed as the same as an output of mysql query. how to achieve my requirement in CodeIgnitor.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check [MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) what is offering.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to accomplish this. 
You can do a query for the parent and then cycle the childs

```
$query_parent = $this->db->query($"
    SELECT *
    FROM parent
    WHERE id = ?", [$parent_id]);

if($query_parent !== FALSE && $query_parent->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $result_array_parent = $query_parent->result_array();
    $query_parent->free_result();

    foreach ($result_array_parent as $k_p => $v_p)
    {
        $query_child = $this->db->query($"
            SELECT *
            FROM child
            WHERE id = ?", [$v_p['id']);

        if($query_child !== FALSE && $query_child->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $result_array_child = $query_child->result_array();
            $query_child->free_result();

            foreach ($result_array_child as $k_c => $v_c)
            {
                $result_array_parent[$k_p]["child_".$k_c] = $v_c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or do a Join query and then transform it to an array.